# How to specify a git merge "ours" strategy with .gitattributes for deleted files?

Tags: git, branch

I have 2 branches in my project: A (master) & B. In branch B some of the files that are in master have been deleted. I want to avoid merge conflicts when there are changes in master to files that have been deleted in B.

I have added the files to `.gitattributes`, e.g.

```
README.adoc merge=ours
```

For my merge driver I have

```
[merge "ours"]
name = Always keep mine during merge
driver = true
```

However I still get conflicts and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
git merge master
CONFLICT (modify/delete): README.adoc deleted in HEAD and modified in master. Version master of README.adoc left in tree.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have run `git check-attr` and it shows

```
README.adoc: merge: ours
```

I've also tried `GIT_TRACE=2` but it provides no useful info; it only tells me where it is getting the binaries from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `modify/delete` conflict is a *high level* conflict.  Merge drivers, defined in `.gitattributes`, are used only for solving *low level* conflicts: the merge driver is used only when the file (a) exists in all three versions (base and both branch tips) and (b) differs in all three versions.  Here, the file exists in two versions—base and one branch tip—and differs in those two versions, but the third version is simply deleted entirely, and the merge driver is never invoked.

For the `recursive`, `resolve`, and `subtree` strategies, high level conflicts always result in a merge conflict and a suspended-in-mid-process merge.  High level conflicts simply never occur in the `ours` strategy (`-s ours`, very different from the `-X ours` extended-option) as it looks only at the current tree.  High level conflicts in `octopus` are (I think) fatal: the octopus merge is aborted entirely.<sup>2</sup>

> I want to avoid merge conflicts when there are changes in A to files that have been deleted in B.

To do this, you must write a *merge strategy*.  This is hard.<sup>1</sup>  See my answer to [git "trivial" merge strategy that directly commits merge conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58757832/1256452).

---

<sup>1</sup>The main evidence I have for "hard" is the fact that Git comes with those five strategies—`resolve`, `recursive`, `ours`, `octopus`, and `subtree`—and despite well over a decade of development, Git still has only those five strategies.

<sup>2</sup>I never actually do octopus merges, so my experience here is limited.

Comment: A merge strategy is applied to every file in merge right? Or is there some way to apply a specific strategy to certain files? If not then if I were to write a strategy it would have to do a normal merge and if it failed, detect the cause as modify/delete conflict and, if so, implement ours. Right? It does sound hard.

Comment: The merge strategy is *responsible for* merging every file. It's run just once, by whichever command invokes the merge. Basically the front end `git merge` command parses arguments and figures out which strategy the user asked for, after which *your code does all the work*.